# How to Make a Semi Circle Dashed Progress Bar React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, circular-dependency, progress

I want to make a semi-circle Dashed progress bar with the ability to change total number of dashed bars and filled bars. I want to make a view like in the image.
I have used DashedProgress Library, but couldn't cut the circle to half circle.

What I want
[image]

What I have achieved yet.
[image]

Comment: Just checked the src of`react-native-dashed-progress` (https://github.com/websoptimization/react-native-dashed-progress/blob/master/dashed-progress/index.js). 
 I guess you can come up with your own solution using react-native-svg => https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg.